# How to identify registry operations are redirected/reflected?

Tags: driver, minifilter

When we register registry callbacks using **CmRegisterCallbackEx**, how to identify callbacks  we receive for registry operation are redirected/reflected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CmRegisterCallbackEx will call your function for every operation. It is your functions responsibility to handle the operations it needs to and to return STATUS_SUCCESS for operations that it doesn't handle so that Windows knows to call the next filter in the stack. You can read a bit more about this at this link: [Registry Filter Drivers (Part 1)](http://lordjeb.com/2014/01/14/registry-filter-drivers-part-1/).